How to query to get random document with Referenced Documents
I have 3 collections(User, Credit and Status). Every User have 1 Credit data and Many Status Data like this:
Users Document
[
  {
  "_id": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb41"),
  "Name": "First User"
  },
  {
  "_id": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb42"),
  "Name": "Second User"
  },
  {
  "_id": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb43"),
  "Name": "Third User"
  }
]

Credit Document
[
  {
  "_id": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb44"),
  "userId": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb41"),
  "credit": 100
  },
  {
  "_id": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb45"),
  "userId": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb42"),
  "credit": 10
  },
  {
  "_id": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb46"),
  "userId": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb43"),
  "credit": 100
  }
]

Status Document
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb47"),
    "userId": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb41"),
    "status": "First User Status",
    "useCredit": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb48"),
    "userId": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb42"),
    "status": "Second User Status",
    "useCredit": 20
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb49"),
    "userId": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb42"),
    "status": "Second User Status",
    "useCredit": 10
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb4a"),
    "userId": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb43"),
    "status": "Third User Status",
    "useCredit": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("669fbdac704d41e9040cbb4c"),
    "userId": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb43"),
    "status": "Third User Status",
    "useCredit": 4
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("669fbdac704d41e9040cbb4d"),
    "userId": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb43"),
    "status": "Third User Status",
    "useCredit": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("669fbdac704d41e9040cbb50"),
    "userId": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb43"),
    "status": "Third User Status",
    "useCredit": 2
  }
]

I want to get random Status with:

userId of Status not equal with User "_id"
User Credit equal or greater than useCredit of Status

Example:
If First User do query, he will get one random data from Status Document except "_id: 669fbce1704d41e9040cbb47"(because own status) and "_id: 669fbce1704d41e9040cbb48" (because, credit not enough).
I am thinking using aggregate but I don't figure out how to do it..

Can you revise your sample documents as I'm confused about the ObjectId's. For example in the credit documents they all have the same _id and in the status documents there are matching _id so what is intentional and what is a typo. It would be really helpful to just use real/realistic ObjectId's. You're not leaking important information.

sorry @jQueeny , i have update the sample document

This should fulfill the purpose
db.Status.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      userId: { $ne: ObjectId("123") } // Replace "123" with the current user's _id
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Credit",
      localField: "userId",
      foreignField: "userId",
      as: "creditInfo"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$creditInfo"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gte: ["$creditInfo.credit", "$useCredit"]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sample: { size: 1 }
  }
]);



thank you so much you save my time, it's works

Use $lookup to chain up the Users and Credit collection. Then, in a $lookup subpipeline, perform your filtered lookup . Add a $sample at the end of the subpipeline to perform the random picking.
db.Users.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      //first user
      "_id": ObjectId("669fbce1704d41e9040cbb41")
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Credit",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "userId",
      "as": "creditLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$creditLookup",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Status",
      "let": {
        uid: "$_id",
        c: "$creditLookup.credit"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              "$and": [
                {
                  $ne: [
                    "$$uid",
                    "$userId"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $gte: [
                    "$$c",
                    "$useCredit"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$sample": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "randomStatus"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$randomStatus",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

Thank you. But, after change First User Credit to 0, i get no document found. Because, the logic depend credit of First User. I hope can query to get random status depends Credit of Status Owner.

@Afdal The problem is caused by unwinding an empty lookup. I have updated the answer with preserveNullAndEmptyArrays option. Not sure if you really need the information in Users collection. It looks to me that it can be denormalized into the Status collection and avoid 1 $lookup
